# calling another page on click from the result of first click in scrapy-splash

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I am scrapping a website where multiple ajax calls are made and contents are displayed.First i am navigating to a page by clicking an option from the home page.From the resulting HTML,i have to make another click and navigate to another page.How to do this using scrapy-splash?

Here is my code

```
import json
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

class SA(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "sa"
    start_urls = ["http://ted.europa.eu/TED/browse/browseByBO.do"]
    def start_requests(self):
        script = """
        function main(splash)
            local url = splash.args.url
            assert(splash:go(url)) #goes to the home url
            assert(splash:wait(1))
            assert(splash:runjs("$('#link-kUK').click()")) #clicks an option in the page

            assert(splash:runjs("$('#filterTree > ul > li:nth-child(1) > a').click()")) #this click has to be done from the resulting html(i am struck with this part) and this click open a new page from where i have to scrap details
            return {
                html = splash:html()
            }
        end
        """
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse_result, meta={
                'splash': {
                    'args': {'lua_source': script},
                    'endpoint': 'execute',
                }
        })

    def parse_result(self, response):
        print("response")
```

Comment: Why is a large part of your code commented out? If the code is not part of your question, please remove it.

Comment: @Tony,Actually it is not commented out,it is a lua-source-script.You can refer scrapy-splash https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash.Thanks

Comment: Apologies, I misread your code.